# Completely remove attribute from Backbone.js model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I am trying to totally remove an attribute from a backbone model.  The model is being sent to an API that isn't very flexible, and it will break if I send additional attributes over the ones I'm supposed to send, so I need to remove an attribute so it no longer exists.

I tried `model.unset`, from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605730/remove-an-attribute-from-a-backbone-js-model), but when I print out the object the attribute I'm trying to remove is still listed, just with a value of null.

I need the attribute to be completely gone.

**My basic structure is:**

```
model.unset("AttrName", "silent");
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the parameters for `unset` incorrectly.  "Silent" should be a part of an [options hash](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-unset), not a separate parameter.  This works:

```
model.unset("AttrName", { silent: true });
```

---

The reason for the strange behavior can be seen from the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html):

```
unset: function(attr, options) {
  (options || (options = {})).unset = true;
  return this.set(attr, null, options);
},
```

The `unset` method assumes that its `options` parameter is an object, and attempts to either create or modify it, then passes it on to the `set` method.  If you pass a string instead, then the inadvertent effect of the code is to set the attribute to null, rather than to unset it.

Comment: If I change the options to be a hash like that it triggers a change event, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid with the silent option.

Comment: @FrizbeeFanatic14 something else is wrong -- if you use that syntax, it shouldn't raise a change event (I just tested this).

Comment: You're right, it was something else calling that event.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Override the toJSON method of your model and only include the attributes you wish to send.

**Updated**: (added code sample)

When extending the model, add a toJSON function and return an object with the desired attributes:

```
{
    toJSON : function() {
        return {
            name: this.get('name'),
            age: this.get('age'),
            phoneNumber: this.get('phoneNumber')
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to Backbone - how exactly would I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

You might try just building an object with only the properties you want (and sending that):

```
serializeModel: function() {
  return {
    email: this.$("#email").val(),
    password: this.$("#password").val()
  }
}
```